# android canvas onDraw timing

Tags: android, timing, ondraw

1. I am making an Android game in which some graphical elements move fast.
   I am going to use Canvas but fear that the onDraw method will be called at irregular interevals making the fast elements move at irregular speeds.
   Is there a way to make sure that the onDraw method is called at regular intervals.
2. Alternately if I can get the system time in msec I can take the  difference between two consecutive calls to onDraw and based on the speed of these fast elements make the their movement smooth.

Kindly help,

Sameer

Answer (score 2):

> I am going to use Canvas but fear that the onDraw method will be called at irregular interevals making the fast elements move at irregular speeds

You should **not** update the position of objects in `onDraw()`, because:

- Indeed, the method might not be called at predefined intervals
- It is meant to **draw** objects, not update objects

Instead, update the objects/world in another method that you call at regular intervals using a timer.

After updating the world, call `invalidate()` on your `View` to trigger the `onDraw()` method. If your application has some spare time it will be called. If not, no problem since the `world update method` will keep on running and thus updating your world.

(Of course, if your application is *too* busy the view is never updated and you have problems to solve!)

> Alternately if I can get the system time in msec I can take the difference between two consecutive calls to onDraw and based on the speed of these fast elements make the their movement smooth.

This is the way to go in the 'world update method'!
It will correct for the irregular timer intervals.